# Run time Error in converting application from .NET 2.0 to 4.5.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.5, .net-2.0

I'm trying to convert my application from **.NET 2.0 to 4.5.1** but I got the with the run time version of my application.

> Could not load file or assembly '...dll' or one of its
>   dependencies.This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the
>   currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

How can I can get rid off this?
Did I forgot something to add or modify on my Web.config?

The process of publishing the application is through local and the published files will be copy paste on the application server in Virtual Machine.

Comment: your project has dependency on other .Net projects ? if yes plz make ur all those projects also get promoted, or other dependencies (third party libraries or controls) must have target framework same as of your source project.

Comment: This requires a bunch of digging - which assemblies? You can check the `web.config` for entries referencing older assemblies (framework or even 3rd party)

Comment: have you updated .net runtime version for application pool too?

Comment: @ijaz - Yup, it was already upgraded to 4.5.1 framework.

Comment: @EdSF - Actually it is working on VS2013 but only in my local, when I published it and copy paste to VM it returned the error on the assemblies. But it was already the newest version.

Comment: @oleksa - Yup I chose the Target Framework of the pool to 4.0

Comment: I'd tried to copy all the upgraded published files from my local to application server(VM), here I got another issue on duplicated script from the web.config:
Config Error:  ** There is a duplicate 'system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler' section defined **
Config Source: <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />

Answer (score 1):

I just solved the issue by publishing the application locally in VS2013,get the published version and add & modified the web.config of the application server instance with the ff:

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="[myDllname].Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web>
    <globalization uiCulture="auto" culture="auto"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <pages validateRequest="false" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="csla" namespace="Csla.Web" assembly="Csla, Version=3.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=93be5fdc093e4c30"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <!--
          Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging
          symbols into the compiled page. Because this
          affects performance, set this value to true only
          during development.
    -->
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <identity impersonate="true"/>
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
  </system.web>
```

Just make sure that the target framework is in compatible mode. In my case, I'm using old CSLA version.